# Redo cardlayout-application into MVC architecture

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, user-interface, cardlayout

So. I've made an application. It has a mainFrame which creates two panels, one holding my wizard-alike buttons (e.g. Next, Previous) and one cardLayout, enabling me to go to either next or previous panel, which I declare in the mainFrame. By having an interface, Verifiable, I'm able to override every window-class a isDataValid()-function which decides whether next and prev buttons should call for cardlayouts flip functions.

The source code can be seen below:

```
public class MainFrame {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dimensions helper");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(5, 5));

        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        contentPane.add(win1);
        Window2 win2 = new Window2();
        contentPane.add(win2);
        Window3 win3 = new Window3();
        contentPane.add(win3);
        Window4 win4 = new Window4();
        contentPane.add(win4);
        Window5 win5 = new Window5();
        contentPane.add(win5);
        Window6 win6 = new Window6();
        contentPane.add(win6);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); 
        final JButton previousButton = new JButton("< PREVIOUS");
        previousButton.setEnabled(false);
        final JButton nextButton = new JButton("NEXT >");
        final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("CANCEL");
        buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);
        buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);

        previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.previous(contentPane);
                Component[] contents = contentPane.getComponents();
                nextButton.setText("NEXT");
                for(Component component : contents) {
                    if(component instanceof Verifiable && component.isVisible()) {
                        Verifiable window = (Verifiable)component;
                        if(window.getIdentifier().equals("FIRST")) {
                            previousButton.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Verifiable verifiable = null;
                Component[] contents = contentPane.getComponents();
                for(Component component : contents) {
                    if(component.isVisible() && component instanceof Verifiable) {
                        verifiable = (Verifiable)component;
                    }
                }
                if(verifiable != null && verifiable.isDataValid()) {
                    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                    cardLayout.next(contentPane); 
                    previousButton.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }
        });



        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });

        frame.add(contentPane);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
} 

public class Window1 extends JPanel implements Verifiable {

    public static final String IDENTIFIER = "FIRST";

    JTextField txtUsername = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField txtPassword = new JPasswordField();

    Database db = new Database();

    public Window1() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:", JLabel.CENTER);
        lblUsername.setBounds(10, 91, 135, 77);
        txtUsername = new JTextField();
        txtUsername.setBounds(155, 116, 188, 27);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:", JLabel.CENTER);
        lblPassword.setBounds(0, 163, 149, 77);
        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
        txtPassword.setBounds(155, 188, 188, 27);
        setLayout(null);

        add(lblUsername);
        add(txtUsername);
        add(lblPassword);
        add(txtPassword);
        String title = "Log in";
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataValid() {
        String username = new String(txtUsername.getText());
        String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());


        try {
            Database conn = di.getDatabaseConnection(username, password);
            di.getTest(conn);
            return true;
            } catch (LoginFailedException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Something went wrong", 
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return IDENTIFIER;
    }
}

interface Verifiable {
    boolean isDataValid();
    String getIdentifier();
}
```

However. I want to redo this application into a Model-View-Controller architecure, meaning that I no longer have any validation code in the Window-classes (i.e. the views). Therefore I've devided the old Window-classes into a WinView-class (Win1) respectively an interface (Interface1) and a Model to verify the data.

```
public class Win1 extends JPanel implements Interface1 {

    JTextField txtUsername = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField txtPassword = new JPasswordField();


    public Win1() {
        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:", JLabel.CENTER);
        txtUsername = new JTextField();
        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:", JLabel.CENTER);
        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();

        setLayout(null);
        add(lblUsername);
        add(txtUsername);
        add(lblPassword);
        add(txtPassword);
        String title = "Log in";
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title)); 

    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return txtUsername.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
        return password;
    }

}

public interface Interface1 {
    String getUsername();
    String getPassword();
}


public class Model {

    Model() {

    }       
}
```

My MainFrame looks the same so far. I get stuck when I'm trying to plan my new architecture. How should I bind the MVC architecture? I'm very happy with how my next and previous buttons work at the moment, is it possible to somehow still use them like I currently do?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want to say is, as far as I understand the MVC methodology (I could be wrong), anything that directly influences how the View itself behaves should remain in the View (like enabling / disabling buttons). Anything else (functional methods) should be handled by a controller.

I would use the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Have a class called `MainController` and use the singleton pattern on that class. Then in your `MainView`, have a global variable of an instance of the `MainController` called `controller`. Then in the controller have a method of `isDataValid(String username, String password)` and call `boolean valid = controller.isDataValid(txtUsername.getText(), new String(txtPassword.getPassword()));`. The same thing could be done with any functional methods. I would also point out that controllers are the only ones which should have any connection to the database for the MVC methodology to work. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, would that work with my wizard-alike idea of having the same outer GUI and only changing the contents with my cardPanel? I like the simplicity of the way I got now, but I know that I eventually would need to migrate to MVC so I better do that now. My wizard should basically function like this:

1. Login followed by a checker when I click next.
2. Some input from the user by a checker when I click next. etc.

Since the user should only be able to type in some data and click next and previous, I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: kentcdodds: Thank you for your feedback, I really appreciate it. I'm new to GUI programming. (Got character limitation on my last comment)

Comment: I see what you mean. Hmm... You may try to have getters on the components you need for the JPanels and handle all the button clicking in the main view. So, have a variable keep track of which panel is up and when the next button is clicked call the getters for the components with the information you need to process user input, then send that information to be processed to the controller.

Comment: kentcdodds: Hm, ok. Would you mind showing some source code how you mean? Would that still work with the same underlying GUI in my MainFrame (i. e. the contentPane and the three buttons)?

Comment: As I've been trying to come up with a good example I keep coming to the conclusion that there are many ways to do this. So I think I'm going to leave it to you. Here are some suggestions:
1. Have a list/map of your cards (JPanels) and each time the next button is pressed loop through the list to find the visible card and do what you need to with it.
2. Have a variable called `currentCard` and set it every time the button is clicked so you know what to do the next time a button is clicked.
3. There are more ways. Just do what suits you best.
If you need me to be more specific, let me know.