# Java, keep global database session in swing application

Tags: java, database, swing, global, cardlayout

Ok. I have a mainframe which contains two containers. One contains my wizard-alike buttons and the other one a contentPane. I have several classes Window1, Window2 etc. which I instantiate in my mainframe class and then toogle through via a cardLayout which decides which Window class to be visible in the contentPane.

Each of these Window classes need a connection to a database. Currently I instantiate a database connection in the window classes separetly but I want some form of a global session where I'm connected from the moment that I passed my Window1 class (also known as the login class) until I close down the application, so that when I get to the other Window classes, I can read and write to the database using this session.

My MainFrame class:

```
public class MainFrame {
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stackoverflowquestion");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(5, 5));

    Database db = new Database();
    //Trying to make some kind of global database instance but fails

    Window1 win1 = new Window1();
    contentPane.add(win1);
    Window2 win2 = new Window2();
    contentPane.add(win2);
    Window3 win3 = new Window3();
    contentPane.add(win3);
    Window4 win4 = new Window4();
    contentPane.add(win4);
    Window5 win5 = new Window5();
    contentPane.add(win5);
    Window6 win6 = new Window6();
    contentPane.add(win6);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); 
    final JButton previousButton = new JButton("< PREVIOUS");
    previousButton.setEnabled(false);
    final JButton nextButton = new JButton("NEXT >");
    final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("CANCEL");
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);
    buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
    buttonPanel.add(nextButton);            

    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            nextButton.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
            Verifiable verifiable = null;
            Component[] contents = contentPane.getComponents();
            for(Component component : contents) {
                if(component.isVisible() && component instanceof Verifiable) {
                    verifiable = (Verifiable)component;
                }
            }
            if(verifiable != null && verifiable.isDataValid()) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.next(contentPane); 
                previousButton.setEnabled(true);
                nextButton.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor()); 

            }
        }
    });

    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(0);
              //Should close the database session
        }

    });

    frame.add(contentPane);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Example of a Window class:

```
public class Window1 extends JPanel implements Verifiable {

public static final String IDENTIFIER = "FIRST";

JTextField txtUsername = new JTextField();
JPasswordField txtPassword = new JPasswordField();

Database db = new Database();
     //As I said, I currently intantiate a database connection separetely which
     //I want to get rid of 
public Window1() {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:", JLabel.CENTER);
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 91, 135, 77);
    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setBounds(155, 116, 188, 27);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:", JLabel.CENTER);
    lblPassword.setBounds(0, 163, 149, 77);
    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.setBounds(155, 188, 188, 27);
    setLayout(null);

    add(lblUsername);
    add(txtUsername);
    add(lblPassword);
    add(txtPassword);
    String title = "Log in";
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
}

@Override
public boolean isDataValid() {
    String username = new String(txtUsername.getText());
    String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());

    try {
        DatabaseConnection conn = db.getDatabaseConnection(username, password, "test", "test", "test");
        db.getTest(conn);
        return true;
        } catch (LoginFailedException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Something went wrong", 
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String getIdentifier() {
    return IDENTIFIER;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the singleton pattern. It basically allows you to have one instance of an object and you can get it anywhere. Learn more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

In my example below, you could have a database connection which you would use to create any calls to the database you would like. I am doing this exact same thing in a project I'm currently working on. It works great :)

Here's an example:

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

  private static DatabaseConnection instance; //note this is static

  private DatabaseConnection() { //note this is private
  }

  public static DatabaseConnection getInstance() { //note this is static
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new DatabaseConnection();
    }
    return instance;
  }
```

You could also try what Wikipedia calls the traditional way (after seeing this I think this is how I'll do it from now on).

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
  private static final DatabaseConnection instance = new DatabaseConnection();

  // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
  private DatabaseConnection() { }

  public static DatabaseConnection getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've read a bit about Singleton pattern but I'm not getting a grip of it. Would you mind showing some code how I could implement it in my current application?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example class using the singleton pattern. Basically, you make the constructor private so the only class which can create it is itself. It also has a global variable called `instance` which is of its own type. Then you have the following method `public static Connection getInstance()` in which you return the variable `instance` (if it's null, first say `instance = new Connection();`). This way you could have one connection to your database and get it wherever you want without having to pass it from one to the other. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your database logic should be totally separate from your GUI. You shouldn't even be giving us your GUI code when asking this question:-) The singleton pattern will work nicely. I would just like to add you probably want to check out commons-dbcp that will handle most of the database connection stuff for you (also uses commons-pooling which will give you connection pooling) http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

Comment: Michael: Well, yeah, I know. However, I find it difficult to migrate my current code into some sort of MVC architecture. If you got any tips I'd gladly accept them.

Comment: @TobiasJohansson, I'm glad it's working for you. If the answer is sufficient. Please accept the answer by checking the check-mark under the arrows so future people will know this was what you were looking for. If you have another question about this I'd be happy to help you in another SO question :)

Comment: @TobiasJohansson, I agree with Michael, you should separate your View from your Model. A really good way to do this is with the Singleton Pattern. Then you would have an object in your view called "controller" and you would use that to handle all functional methods. Does that make sense?

Comment: @kentcdodds: I marked the checker now. Quite new to Stackoverflow. And yes, I know I should and I have tried, but I get stuck when I'm trying to seperate them. I made a question about migrating my current application into MVC style yesterday but I suppose my question was quite vague. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807121/redo-cardlayout-application-into-mvc-architecture

I'd gladly take feedback for that question if you got the time.